# Use Case for External Tables?

Tags: database, database-schema, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Came across [external tables](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tables-external-intro.html) in Snowflake. Could you please share some use cases or benefits for using external tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a data lake in S3 or Azure Blog Storage, for example, huge collection of log files from different sources, you don't have to import that data to Snowflake for analysis. Instead you can simply query it when the files in data lake are linked as external tables.